# why is this program only couting 2 ? no matter what i input

Tags: c++

i was asked to make a program that reads the letter codes A to Z and prints the corresponding telephone digit.
This program uses a sentinel-controlled while loop. To stop the program, the user is prompted for the
sentinel, which is #. e.g MIU= 648 (Just like the old Nokia Phones)
where 2 = (A,B,C)

here is my code but the problem is it only cout's "2" .. any idea why is that ?

```
int main() {

        char x;
        cin >> x;   

        while (x != '#') {

            if (x == 'A', 'B', 'C')
                cout << 2;
            else if (x == 'G', 'H', 'I')
                cout << "4";
            else if (x == 'M', 'N', 'O')
                cout << 6;
            else if (x == 'T', 'U', 'V')
                cout << 8;
            else if (x == 'D', 'E', 'F')
                cout << 3;
            else if (x == 'J', 'K', 'L')
                cout << 5;
            else if (x == 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S')
                cout << 7;
            else if (x == 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
                cout << 9;
                cin >> x;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note : i tried it using a switch it kinda worked only problem is it kept looping for example if i input 'M' it loops 6 for infinity if you can explain why is that, would be great. Thank you

Comment: It has to be `if (x == 'A' || x == 'B' || x == 'C')` and so on.

Comment: Did you see anything remotely resembling `if (x == 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S')`  in your C++ textbook? You don't get to invent semantics.

Comment: and the second cin takes place only in case you input W

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek: Actually that is incorrect. But his indentation is horrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you use the **OR operator** instead of **comma ','** .I am modify your code & attached the screenshot of the program.
Try the below code .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    char x;
    cin >> x;

    while (x != '#') {

        if (x == 'A' || x == 'B' || x == 'C')
            cout << 2;
        else if (x == 'G' || x == 'H' || x == 'I')
            cout << "4";
        else if (x == 'M' || x == 'N' || x == 'O')
            cout << 6;
        else if (x == 'T' || x == 'U' || x == 'V')
            cout << 8;
        else if (x == 'D' || x == 'E' || x == 'F')
            cout << 3;
        else if (x == 'J' || x == 'K' || x == 'L')
            cout << 5;
        else if (x == 'P' || x == 'Q' || x == 'R' || x == 'S')
            cout << 7;
        else if (x == 'W' || x == 'X' || x == 'Y' || x == 'Z')
            cout << 9;
        cin >> x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `,` operator like that in C++.

```
if (x == 'A', 'B', 'C')
    cout << 2;
```

This code will evaluate like the following:
`x == 'A'` to true/false, then throw away the result.
It will then evaluate `B` and throw that away.
It will then evaluate `C` and that will be given to the if.

You need to do

```
if (x == 'A' || x == 'B' || x == 'C')
    cout << 2;
```

How you would sometimes use the `,` in an if statement would be like this.

```
int x=2;
int y;
if (y=x+5, y == 7)
    cout << y << " == 7"; // Works
```

Comment: You _can_ use it - but it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @SirGuy It does compile and it is pretty much guaranteed `y=x+5` will execute  before `y == 7` unless `,` is overloaded which would be pretty unusual.